# Regex - match a character and all its diacritic variations (aka accent-insensitive)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, diacritics, accent-insensitive

I am trying to match a character and all its possible diacritic variations (aka accent-insensitive) with a regular expression. What I could do of course is:

```
re.match(r"^[eēéěèȅêęëėẹẽĕȇȩę̋ḕḗḙḛḝė̄]$", "é")
```

but that is not a general solution. If I use unicode categories like `\pL` I can't reduce the match to a specific character, in this case `e`.

Comment: Does Python regex support the *POSIX character equivalence* match? This is as simple as `[=e=]` – but it also matches its capitalized equivalences, which may be too much in your case. This could be worked around using `(?!\u)`, although this in turn needs your regex to support Uppercase for all Unicode characters as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A workaround to achieve the desired goal would be to use [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to get rid of all diacritics first, and then just match agains the regular `e`

```
re.match(r"^e$", unidecode("é"))
```

Or in this simplified case

```
unidecode("é") == "e"
```

---

Another solution which doesn't depend on the unidecode-library, preserves unicode and gives more control is manually removing the diacritics as follows:

Use [unicodedata.normalize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to turn your input string into normal form D (for decomposed), making sure composite characters like `é` get turned into the decomposite form `e\u301` (e + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)

```
>>> input = "Héllô"
>>> input
'Héllô'
>>> normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", input)
>>> normalized
'He\u0301llo\u0302'
```

Then, remove all codepoints which fall into the category [Mark, Nonspacing](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) (short `Mn`). Those are all characters that have no width themselves and just decorate the previous character.
Use [unicodedata.category()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) to determine the category.

```
>>> stripped = "".join(c for c in normalized if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn")
>>> stripped
'Hello'
```

The result can be used as a source for regex-matching, just as in the unidecode-example above.
Here's the whole thing as a function:

```
def remove_diacritics(text):
    """
    Returns a string with all diacritics (aka non-spacing marks) removed.
    For example "Héllô" will become "Hello".
    Useful for comparing strings in an accent-insensitive fashion.
    """
    normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text)
    return "".join(c for c in normalized if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn")
```