# Strange result of re.match()

Tags: python

`

```
t='1111 si debiteur'
import re
re.match(r"si débiteur",t) is None #gives back True as a result
re.match(r"1111 si débiteur",t) is None #gives back True as a result
re.match(r"1111 si débiteur",t) is not None #gives back False as a result
t='8588'
re.match(r"1111 si débiteur",t) is None #gives back True as a result
```

`

the thing is i don't really get why "re.match(r"1111 si débiteur",t) is None" returning True in both case

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image

Comment: Missing the acute in your original string? Try `1111 si débiteur` instead of `1111 si debiteur`

Comment: yes thank you a lot the question has already been answered

Comment: See also [Regex - match a character and all its diacritic variations (aka accent-insensitive)](/http://stackoverflow.com/q/35783135/3688648)

Answer (score 1):

The value of t: `1111 si debiteur` does not have an *accent*. Where `re.match(r"1111 si débiteur",t)` does.

Comment: aaaaah that was really stupid of me , thanks soo much i've been stuck in this for too long :D