# Java regex: search for a string without accent in a text with accent

Tags: java, regex

In my Java app, I want to use a regex to be able to know if a string exists or not in a text.

The case I want to cover is this one: let's assume that my original text is the following french text (with an accent):

```
démo test
```

I want to know if the word `demo` (without accent) exists in the text, using a regex. The thing is: I can't change the original text (I can't use `Normalizer.normalize()` for example), since I'm using a library that takes a regex as an argument.

Here is what I tried:

- If I use `"(?i)démo"`, there is a match (since `démo` exists)
- If I use `"(?i)demo"`, there is no match, but I also want a match here. I want the regex to be accent insensitive.

So far, I haven't managed to find a regex that can cover that specific case.

Is there any regex that can cover that case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That text doesn't contain `demo` without an accent. Does your matcher say that it does? Please include the code, various input cases and expected output in your question (not the comments).

Comment: should the regex return true when the text is `démo` or only if it is`demo`?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: the regex should tell me that "démo test" and "demo" match.

Comment: Are you processing only french language? Or you may have unknown number of letters with accents?

Comment: You have to Normalize the text first. Does Java do that ?

Comment: do you mean `boolean check = "démo test".matches("[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ\\s]+");`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Yes, only french language

Comment: In this case you have limited number of letters. And you can append them to corresponding normalized letters in your regexp, i.e. "d(e|é)mo"

Comment: Try this `(?i)d[e\xE9\xC9]mo`

Comment: If you _could_ change the input text, the best solution would be to normalize it and remove marks. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35783135/3688648

Comment: Or, you could normalized just the accent characters within your regex, see https://www2.rocketlanguages.com/french/lessons/french-accents/

Comment: @sln Thanks, I already know how french accents work (I'm french), but I don't know how to normalize in the regex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really cannot change the input text, the following works:

If your input text is in decomposed form, meaning that `démo` consists of the unicode codepoints `d` `e` `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT` `m` `o`, you can optionally match the accent:

```
de\pM?mo
```

where `\pM` describes the unicode property ["Mark"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm). This would match all marks. You can also just optionally match `\u0301` directly if you only care about that exact accent

If your text is in *composed* form, meaning `démo` consists of the unicode codepoints `d` `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` `m` `o`, you'll have to just manually match either in the regex:

```
d(e|é)mo
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the regex literal to search and replace the accented
characters with a class.

```
 Regex string           Replace string
---------------------------------------------
Find any one          Replace with this lieral:
of these:

 [aâàä]         ->       [aâàä]
 [cç]           ->       [cç]
 [eéèêë]        ->       [eéèêë]
 [iîï]          ->       [iîï]
 [oô]           ->       [oô]
 [uùûü]         ->       [uùûü]
 [?œ]           ->       ????
```

This requires running 7 separate regexes on the search string.
It would be a global find / replace, seven times.