# how to replace diacritics with basic letters using regular expressions?

Tags: python

I want to replace accented letters with equivalent basic letters using regular expressions.

Example: **Û --> U**

I have seen solutions where they search for ALL accented letters. But I'm looking for a  better and more direct solution like :

someone suggested this in JAVA:

```
\p{Diacritic}/gu
```

or this in python

```
def remove_diacritics(text):
"""
Returns a string with all diacritics (aka non-spacing marks) removed.
For example "Héllô" will become "Hello".
Useful for comparing strings in an accent-insensitive fashion.
"""
normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text)
return "".join(c for c in normalized if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn")
```

But Im looking for a way without having to go through normalization

Comment: Does this not do what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783135/regex-match-a-character-and-all-its-diacritic-variations-aka-accent-insensiti

Comment: Can you explain why normalization is not 'direct' enough?

Comment: my question was how to do this with regular expressions

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: I just want to know if there is way to do it with just regular expression.

Comment: I also tried the normalization way. Somehow the Û always stays Û.

Comment: `remove_diacritics("Û")` gives me `'U'`.

Comment: There was a mistake in my code. It works now so THANK YOU .. I appreciate your help

Comment: The normalization is necessary to make the problem tractable. Without normalization, the same grapheme could be represented in multiple ways, and trying to handle it with regex would require handling *all* the different representations. Normalization simplifies to handling a specific representation, not all possible representations. I'll also note, the set of all diacritic marked characters is huge, so unless you're limiting yourself to just latin-1, an exhaustive regex gets ugly quickly.

Comment: I understand .. thanks